# Verify site for Android Instant Apps without Digital Assets Links and https?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

is it possible to use Instant Apps just with Google Webmaster Tools verification (*like I did before with app-indexing*) -> [Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools)

Or maybe, this time it is necessary to use https + DAL?  [Handling Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#web-assoc)

Currently we don't use https, this is why we need the other solution.

I couldn't find the answer in Instant Apps documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must use **HTTPS** and **Google Digital Asset Links**.

From the second paragraph of your link

[Handling Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html)

> Automatic handling of links requires the cooperation of app developers
>   and website owners. A developer must configure their app to declare
>   associations with one or more websites, and to request that the system
>   verify those associations. A website owner **must**, in turn, **provide that**
>   **verification by publishing a Digital Asset Links file**. A Digital Asset
>   Links file is a collection of statements conforming to the Asset Links
>   protocol that make public, verifiable assertions about other apps or
>   websites.

And later on that same page:

> **Important**: The system verifies the `JSON` file via the encrypted `HTTPS`
>   protocol. Make sure that your hosted file is accessible over an `HTTPS`
>   connection, regardless of whether your app's intent filter includes
>   `https`.

Comment: Hi, thx for You response. I was asked about DAL, because when I integrated Appindexing there were two options: DAL (recommended) and Google Webmaster Tools ([App indexing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/public-content#associate-your-site-and-your-app)). 

So maybe it is just lack of information about second option in documentation, but it still exist?

Comment: Per the docs, you must use DAL + https. Google Webmaster Tools are not supported by Instant Apps. Adding https support is relatively inexpensive and may be [free](https://letsencrypt.org/) depending on your use case.

Comment: If i am using an internal/staging environment, should that work? the production environment has no such config files, i believe only the client app checks the file, in this sentence "the system verifies the JSON file via HTTPS", the system means the client device/OS, right?